# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass when using API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http, ruby-on-rails-5, httparty

This is obviously a common error. However, I am unable to resolve this issue when going over my code. I am trying to access ProPublica's API for congress. My model, view, and controller is pretty straightforward and this exact code has worked with me when accessing the Google News API.

I keep getting an undefined method error when I try and use the ".each" method in my view to iterate through the JSON response. I believe that I am passing the proper headers to the API as it requests.

My models:

```
class CongressTracker < ApplicationRecord
  include HTTParty

  def self.response
    #congress = "most recent congress"
    #chamber = "one each for congress and senate"
    #type = "introduced, passed, etc."

    congress_url = "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/senate/bills/passed.json"

    HTTParty.get(congress_url,
        :headers => {
        "X-API-KEY" => "api-key-here"
        })
  end
end


class Bill < ApplicationRecord
  include HTTParty
end
```

My controller:

```
class BillsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @response = CongressTracker.response
  end
end
```

My view:

```html
<% @response["results"].each do |bill| %>
      <p><%= bill["title"]%></p>
      <p><%= bill["summary"]%></p>
  <% end %>
```

My route:

```
resources :bills
```

The error in detail:

```
  Rendering bills/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered bills/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 312ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <% @response["results"].each do |bill| %>
    2:       <p><%= bill["title"]%></p>
    3:       <p><%= bill["summary"]%></p>
    4:   <% end %>

app/views/bills/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_bills_index_html_erb__2110131784793159686_70138696839360'
```

Example of expected JSON response (which I can get to work in the terminal):

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "copyright":"Copyright (c) 2017 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
   "results":[
      {
         "congress": "115",
         "chamber": "Senate",
         "num_results": "20",
         "offset": "0",
         "bills": [
              {
                 "bill_id": "hr2825-115",
                 "bill_type": "hr",
                 "number": "H.R.2825",
                 "bill_uri": "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/bills/hr2825.json",
                 "title": "DHS Authorization Act of 2017",
                 "summary": "",
              },
```

Comment: What's the content of `@response`, don't you have to parse it?

Comment: I believe that HTTParty has it's own way of parsing JSON. This exact code works with the Google News API that I am also using so I don't think that it is an issue with parsing the JSON response.

Comment: One thing you can try is throwing a `<%= debug @response %>` into the view and verifying the response structure and from there if it's off you might be able to track down what changed or why it's different than what you're expecting from there

Comment: Sadly, trying to debug didn't give me any additional information.

Comment: Can you replace the content of your view with `<%= @response.parsed_response %>` and tell us what it renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` error, is most likely because the response is `{"message"=>"Forbidden"}`, because your API key is incorrect.

I tested your code, and everything works correctly as long as you have the correct API key.

You have some mistakes with your view, most likely because you don't have the results yet.

To get the title and the summary of the bills you will need something like this:

```
<% @response["results"].each do |result| %>
  <% result["bills"].each do |bill| %>
    <p><%= bill["title"]%></p>
    <p><%= bill["summary"]%></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'll double check my key and alter my view. Thank you! This has been given me pause for hours.

Comment: I marked this as the answer yesterday, but didn't get to test and make sure until today. It was indeed the correct answer. I accidentally used the wrong API key. Thanks again!